# URL host deprecated but replacement crashes

Tags: ios, swift, macos, url, foundation

URL [host](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780168-host) was deprecated on `iOS 16.1` and `macOS 13` but the replacement crashes under certain scenarios.

The replacement option is [host(percentEncoded:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3988461-host)

#### Example:

```swift
let url = URL(string: "lorem.com")
print(url?.host) // deprecated warning, prints nil
print(url?.host()) // crash: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18084f9d4)
```

While `lorem.com` doesn't conform to `RFC 1808` (the most common form of URL), requesting it's host used to return `nil`, as opposed to crashing.

Same behaviour both using `host(percentEncoded: true)` or `host(percentEncoded: false)`.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Seems to be crashing only if there's no scheme in the URL string. As a workaround you can use `let host = url?.scheme == nil ? nil : url?.host()` but indeed, it seems to be a bug and probably will be fixed. So keeping the "old" `host` seems to be more reasonable solution.

Comment: @Gergely, Indeed, if the URL is missing a scheme then as mentioned it is not conforming to `RFC 1808`. But the main point here is that it is unsafe to migrate to the new functionality.

Comment: @Gergely Unfortunately, testing for scheme wouldn't be enough because you can have a scheme yet still miss a host, e.g. `URL(string: "https://")`, it seems like using the deprecated property is the only workaround.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug on the **Foundation** framework and I have opened a bug report on the Feedback Assistant.

While it gets fixed I propose to continue using the deprecated version of `host`, otherwise you will have crashes in code that was previously working, specially if you depended on host to return nil under certain cases.

Comment: Has there been any reply to your bug report? This still seems to be an issue on iOS 16.5

Comment: @user1046037 no answer or updates on the bug report I created. I recommend doing the same, as the more reports they receive the more likely it gets prioritised earlier.